# Cannot delete junction as admin

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have a junction point in Windows 11 which points to a deleted folder, and I cannot delete it in any way. `takeown` reports success takin ownership, but then neither `rmdir` nor `fsutil reparsepoint delete` can delete it - each time I get "Access Denied", even I'm working as an admin in the shell. Does anyone have any ideas how to delete such abomination?

Comment: Taking ownership does not change permissions, that is a separate step. Did you do that?

Comment: @kreemoweet that's actually a hard thing to do - seems there is no option to edit permissions, even for the owner. I can only view effective permissions on that folder for various users, but nothing is editable.

Comment: Get-Acl shows `Allow  FullControl` yet I'm still getting access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a few process privileges that allow bypassing file permissions – similar to what root can do in Unix-like systems (except in Windows there's an intermediate state of "granted but disabled" – all Administrators have these privileges granted to them by default, but a process still needs to manually activate them before using).

From an elevated (Admin) PowerShell, do:

1. Install the PSPrivilege module from Microsoft's PSGallery:

   ```
   Install-Module -Name PSPrivilege -Scope CurrentUser
   ```

   (It's a third-party module, but its author is fairly well known for his Python and PowerShell/.NET projects in this area.)
2. Enable the "Backup" and "Restore" privileges:

   ```
   Enable-ProcessPrivilege SeBackupPrivilege, SeRestorePrivilege
   ```

   This will only have effect on the current PowerShell window.
3. Now you should be able to delete objects regardless of their ACL:

   ```
   del -Force the_bad_junction
   ```

(Another way to do what Enable-ProcessPrivilege does is to install ProcExp or Process Hacker, open the Properties window for the powershell.exe process, then use the "Token" tab to enable the privileges.)

---

There might be a few reasons why you're getting "Access Denied" that have nothing to do with file permissions (including e.g. file integrity levels; antivirus software or other weird drivers; or trying to do this over a network share when the server decides you don't have the rights to).

If the disk is local, you can connect it to a Linux system which will just ignore all NTFS ACLs and all driver-imposed restrictions:

1. Make yourself a Linux live CD/USB that has ntfs-3g bundled (e.g. Ubuntu will do).
2. If needed, temporarily disable Secure Boot.
3. Boot into Windows again, then *reboot* from Windows into Linux. (Specifically use "Reboot", not "Shut down", so that Windows will fully dismount NTFS partitions and you won't need to mess around with disabling Fast Startup.)
4. Delete what needs to be deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately, psprivilege did not help.